# How to write strings in different places of a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

in the code below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp ;
    fp = fopen("out.txt", "r+");
    int count = 1;
    char ch ;
    char userInput[5] ;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (lineNumber!= -1){
        fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
        lineNumber = atoi(userInput);
        while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
            if(ch=='\n')  //counts number of lines
                count++;
            if(count == lineNumber)
            {
                fprintf(fp, "writed %d\n", count);
                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a string in the line which the user gives me,i store the user answer in `userInput`and then convert it to the int and store it in `lineNumber`.
when i try to write fore example in line 90 (my file has 100 lines) two error i get:
1.the file reduce to a 91-line file (instate of remain 100 lines)
2.although i seek to first of file,no more lines written in the next loops and user inputs.

Comment: "lines" implies a text file.  Overwriting lines will only work if the new line is *exactly* the same length as the original.  If not then you might overwrite the "\n" end-of-line marker (if it is longer) or just overwrite part of the line if it is shorter.  Text files do not contain separate records, they are a continual stream of bytes punctuated by new-line ("\n") characters to mark line endings.

Comment: @cdarke ok,so how can i seek to the first of my file without closing it?

Comment: Use a temp file.  Open source, open temp, copy to point of insertion, write new stuff, continue copying until end of source, close, close, delete source, rename.

Comment: To illustrate, if you are on UNIX/Linux/OS X try on the command-line: `od -xc out.txt` which displays a dump of the bytes in the file.

Comment: You can't.  Do what @MartinJames says.  That is, you have to effectively copy the file line by line, making changes as you go.  The alternative is to write your own Indexed file system, or to use a database - a text file is not a suitable format for random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a file (to count its lines) and then turning around and writing to it is tricky.  Among other things, you have to do something like an `fseek` *between* the reading and the writing.  So try interchanging the order of the `fseek` and `fprintf` calls:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fprintf(fp, "writed %d\n", count);
```

Also, be aware that unless the new text you're writing ("writed ###") is *exactly* the same length as whatever line used to be there, the line structure of the remainder of the file is likely to get garbled.

See also [this question](http://c-faq.com/stdio/fupdate.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).